# Definir largura para editor nicEdit

Tags: jquery, editor-de-texto

Alguem sabe definir a largura do editor nicEdit?

Comment: Você quer definir `inline`? Se sim, é só usar HTML simples: `width: 100px`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defina no seu **textarea** no seu ***style*** o `width:` no valor de `100%` ou em pixel o valor desejado (`300px`), exemplo:

```
<textarea name="area" style="width: 100%;">
    Some Initial Content was in this textarea
</textarea>
```

---

```
<textarea name="area" style="width: 300px;">
    HTML content default in textarea
</textarea>
```

***Site referência:*** [**Demo -  NicEdit**](http://nicedit.com/demos.php)

Comment: Não sabia que tinha que definir direto no componente, Agradeço novamente maria.

Comment: Não @Marconi ... esse comportamento estranho você poderia abrir outro questionamento ...